# permutations of length N of N natural numbers from 1,2,3.....N such that no two consecutive numbers are equal.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

For given n, I need to find sum of count of most occurring number for each permutation of length n.(such that no two consecutive numbers are equal).

for e.g. for n=3    1 2 3 will give 3 as the count of most occurring numbers..because each 1,2,3 is occurring 1 time.

1 2 1 will give 1 as 1 is occurring twice.
2 3 2 will give 1 as 2 is occurring twice.

n=3 will have 12 such permutations and ans will be sum of all counts.

i tried to generalize it for N.
but I failed as number of permutations grow rapidly.
please help.

ex.

if we have 4 combinations of length 3.

1 2 3---> count 3 all occuring equal number of times.
1 2 1---> count 1 (only 1 is occuring maximum number of times)

1 3 1-->  count 1
2 1 2--> count 1

ans= 3+1+1+1

Comment: These are not permutations, but combinations with repetitions.

Comment: very bad phrasing... give an example of what you mean by sum of count and what exactly you want

Comment: @Awesome 
for each combination ans will be the count of most occuring numbers.(if all  N numbers are occuring equal number of times, ans will be N).

final ans will be summation of ans for each combination.

Comment: that isn't a combination but a permutation with repetition as order matters

Comment: @Awesome

i added an example.

Comment: So, let me rephrase the problem as follows. Consider all ordered $n$-tuples with elements from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, such that elements which are next to each other in the tuple differ. Let $f(x)$ be the number of _different_ elements which are tied as "most frequent" in the tuple $x$. Sum $f$ over all such $n$-tuples.

Comment: Someone else has just posted a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1223877/strange-candy-distribution-no-two-adjacent-students-get-same-number-of-candies

Comment: @AndrewWoods Solution?

Comment: Where does the problem come from?