# Strange Candy Distribution, No two adjacent students get same number of candies.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

There are **N students** and professor has **N<sup>2</sup> candies**. Students get **at least 1** and **at most N** candies and **no two adjacent students should get same number of candies**. Professor makes the frequency chart for number of candies distributed to students.
How many ways professor can distribute candies such that there are at most N students having maximum frequency.
**Example**
N=3
(Candy) (Freq) (Max Freq Count)
(1, 2, 3) [1 1 1] => 3
(1, 3, 2) [1 1 1] => 3
(2, 1, 3) [1 1 1] => 3
(2, 3, 1) [1 1 1] => 3
(3, 1, 2) [1 1 1] => 3
(3, 2, 1) [1 1 1] => 3
(1, 2, 1) [2 1 0] => 1
(1, 3, 1) [2 0 1] => 1
(2, 1, 2) [1 2 0] => 1
(2, 3, 2) [0 2 1] => 1
(3, 1, 3) [1 0 2] => 1
(3, 2, 3) [0 1 2] => 1

Thus **6 ways** for 1 student having max frequency. **0 ways** for 2 students having max frequency. **6 ways** for 3 students having max frequency.

How to solve this using combinations.

Comment: I don't understand how, say, $(2,1,2)$ evaluates to 1 student at max frequency count. Unless you meant 1 candy-count at max frequency.

Comment: It looks very similar to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222613/permutations-of-length-n-of-n-natural-numbers-from-1-2-3-n-such-that-no-two

Comment: @Maths Fun I see what you did there...

Comment: @Joffan (2, 1, 2) is candy distribution and the frequency is [1 2 0] now there is just one number that is maximum. so it's 1

Comment: There are 2 students that have 2 candies. So the number of *students* getting the maximum frequency count of candies is 2. However the number of *candy-counts* at maximum frequency is only 1. If that is what you mean, you should edit your question.